TypeError python ollama
from langchain_community.llms import ollama
llm=ollama(base_url='http://localhost:11434',model="llama 2")


I'm encountering a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error while attempting to use the Ollama LLM in VS Code on my Windows machine. The Ollama server is running successfully on localhost:11434, as verified through my terminal.
My ollma LLM is working properly in terminal but giving this error when being called
Please help with this query

Does this answer your question? TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

No im not able to solve my problem from the given  explanation

Once I faced the same issue. Issue is that in Ollama the "O" needs to be capital in import and usage. Below should work:
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
llm = Ollama(model="llama2")

